# Angular Unexpected token

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to follow the official tutorial of Angular, and I'm stuck at a point. I have a object Card in card.ts :

```js
export class Card {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

And I'm importing this object to another file, and I instantiate an array of Card :

```js
import { Card } from './card';

export const CARDS: Card[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Choc' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Sillage' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Vrasqua' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

Of course both file are in the same directory. But I have this error :

```
./src/app/mock_card.js 3:18
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:18)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { Card } from './card';
| 
> export const CARDS: Card[] = [
|   { id: 11, name: 'Choc' },
|   { id: 12, name: 'Sillage' },
```

It looks like my Card object is not recognized. But I declared and use a `Card` variable in another .ts file and it works (I imported it in the same way). Do you have any idea why it is happenning?

EDIT : I renamed mock_card.js with mock_card.ts and it works

Comment: The message coplains about the file `mock_card.js`. Aren't you using TypeScript? It should be `mock_card.ts`. (side note: Card is a *class* not an *object*. An object is an *instance* of a class).

Comment: Yes I use typescript. Thank you, that is the dumbest error I ever had

Comment: Voting to close for typo.